# Confusing behavior in Rust push method

Tags: rust

I have a Formula which is defined like the following:

```
pub type Variable = char;

#[derive(Clone,Debug,PartialEq,Eq)]
pub enum Atom {
    Base(Variable),
    Not(Variable)
}

pub type Clause = Vec<Atom>;

pub type Formula = Vec<Clause>;
```

Next I have a method like so:

```
pub fn dpll(f:& mut Formula) -> bool {
    let mut formulaClone = f.clone();
    let v = 'a';
    let finalVect = formulaClone.push(vec![Atom::Base(v)]);
   
}
```

Now for some reason finalVect is assigned a type of (). I cannot figure out why? Shouldn't it be a type of &mut Formula? Because pushing to a vector doesn't change its type? Why does pushing to the vector modify its type in this case?

After hearing some suggestions:
It seems like push method returns a () so how would I do the following then:

```
pub fn dpll(f:& mut Formula) -> bool {
    let mut formulaClone = f.clone();
    let v = 'a';
    let finalVect = formulaClone.push(vec![Atom::Base(v)]);
    let finalVect2 = formulaClone.push(vec![Atom::Not(v)]);
    return dpll(finalVect) || dpll(finalVect2);
}
```

In which case I want to recursively call dpll with the new parameters formulaClone + vec![Atom::Base(v)] and formulaClone + vec![Atom::Not(v)].

Comment: [`push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.push) doesn't return anything, so it returns `()` "by default".

Comment: @caTS yes but im assigning finalVect to formulaClone with the extra element added to it so why doesnt it assign it to the whole vector but to ()?

Comment: What do you mean? `formulaClone.push` **doesn't return a vector**. It modifies `formulaClone` *in place*. That's why you need to make it mutable before using the method.

Comment: @caTS So how do I make finalVect do what I expect it to do than? Namely give me formulaClone with an element appended to it? Because as it stands () is completely useless.

Comment: Why do you need `finalVect`? You changed `formulaClone` already. Just use that...

Comment: So okay going back to the question I updated it @caTS so what do I do?

Comment: @chen clone `f` twice, push to the respective clones, call `dpll` on the clones (preferably adding some sort of termination condition unless you want to blow the stack)

Comment: If you need a mutable reference to the last item in vec (for example one just added) you can use [last_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.last_mut).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't assign the return values of push to anything.

```rust
pub fn dpll(f: &mut Formula) -> bool {
    let mut formulaClone = f.clone();
    let v = 'a';
    formulaClone.push(vec![Atom::Base(v)]);
    let mut finalVect = formulaClone.clone();
    formulaClone.push(vec![Atom::Not(v)]);
    let mut finalVect2 = formulaClone.clone();
    return dpll(&mut finalVect) || dpll(&mut finalVect2);
}
```

if we go with your literal code.

Or a little more cleaned up:

```rust
pub fn dpll(mut f: Formula) -> bool {
    let v = 'a';
    f.push(vec![Atom::Base(v)]);
    let finalVect = f.clone();
    f.push(vec![Atom::Not(v)]);
    return dpll(finalVect) || dpll(f);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `finalVect.push` on the 5th line?

Comment: It wouldn't work since `finalVect` isn't `mut` also the result would be the same since it is a clone of f at that point.